# Insert into withy select : ! #1062 - Duplicate entry '222-104276' for key 'cry_id'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1062

I have a following table :

dct_cry_id............cry_id............dct_id..........classify........dct_connection_id
(...)
71........................13............104276..............70..............0
2110......................29............104276..............7...............0
2111......................37............104276..............8...............0
2112......................38............104276..............6...............0
(...)
591.......................13............154614..............540.............0
2090......................36............154614..............46..............0
2091......................30............154614..............2...............0
(...)

I use following query

```
I use following query
INSERT INTO mytabletest1 (cry_id,`dct_id`)
-- VALUES (222)
SELECT  
222, `dct_id`

FROM `mytabletest1`
WHERE `cry_id`
NOT IN 
(
112, 115, 116, 117, 118,
973, 974, 975, 976, 977,
8 
)
```

And I have unfortunately, i have following warning/error message :

> "! #1062 - Duplicate entry '222-104276' for key 'cry_id'"

**Why I have a this message ?**

After this, I checked my table, my query **worked**  :
dct_cry_id............cry_id............dct_id..........classify........dct_connection_id
(...)
71........................13............104276..............70..............0
2110......................29............104276..............7...............0
2111......................37............104276..............8...............0
2112......................38............104276..............6...............0
**153876....................222...........104276..............0...............0**
(...)
591.......................13............154614..............540.............0
2090......................36............154614..............46..............0
2091......................30............154614..............2...............0
**15870.....................222...........154614..............0...............0**
(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will return the key  '222-104276' 4 times. The record was inserted once and error was raised on second insert.

Comment: Why 4 times ?

How can my query return only one time ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying here. You can use distinct clause to remove the duplicates as follows                                                                                                  SELECT Distinct 222, `dct_id`
FROM `mytabletest1`
WHERE `cry_id`
NOT IN (112, 115, 116, 117, 118,973, 974, 975, 976, 977,8 )

Comment: It works with distinct :SELECT Distinct 222, dct_id FROM mytabletest1 WHERE cry_id NOT IN (112, 115, 116, 117, 118,973, 974, 975, 976, 977,8 )